# Could not create Azure Deployment Slot- WebsiteExtension Error

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I've tried to create a new deployment slot for my website, but I got the following error
[image]

The problem was I could not create a new deployment slot and the error is in the screenshot itself and from the question title "WEBSITEEXtension" ???
Could you please let me know how to fix this? I use the latest version of Chrome on windows 10.

Comment: What exactly is the error you're seeing? (It looks like the slots blade failed to load, is there an error beyond that?)

Comment: The error is in the screenshot WebsiteExtension

Comment: I was asking because this looks as if this blade is having issues loading and wanted to know if it was giving anything more descriptive elsewhere on the page. 
What have you tried? Have you tried clearing your cookies or trying a different browser? (As you know, websiteextension is non-informative.)

Comment: Also: I was unable to reproduce your error, which leads me to believe it may be local or transient.

Comment: That is the reason why I asked, I tried again and again but it didn't work. Finally, I tried to use the old portal then I could create a new deployment slot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could create a new deployment slot by using the old portal https://manage.windowsazure.com. I think that the script on the new portal has some issue.